# How to define Gatsby markdown page paths in one file?

Tags: graphql, gatsby, static-site

Bu default, [Gatsby](http://gatsbyjs.org) uses [frontmatter](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/#create-static-pages-using-gatsbys-node-api) for defining paths, like:

```
---
path: /example-page
---
```

and then works with it via GraphQL.

What is the best way to define those paths for all markdown files by not writing frontmatter part in every file, but in one file, as an instance, like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Example",
        "path": "/example-page.md"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by adding the path when the page is created.

Add this in `gatsby-node` :

```
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`);

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, getNode, boundActionCreators }) => {

  const { createNodeField } = boundActionCreators

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {

    const slug = createFilePath({
      node,
      getNode,
      basePath: `pages`
    })

    createNodeField({
      node,
      name: `slug`,
      value: `/pages${slug}`
    })

  }

};
```

`createFilePath` turn markdown files in `pages` directory into `/pages/slug`.

`createNodeField` creates new query'able field with name of 'slug'.

Now in `graphql` you can access the slug :

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark {
    edges {
      node {
        fields {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can create your pages as usual using the new slug field as page path.

With that you can add your title and all you want in data accessible in graphql.

Example here : https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/